# How to make an EAR file using JDev 10.1.3.4 from an EJB Application?

Tags: jdeveloper

How to make an EAR file using JDev 10.1.3.4 from an EJB Application???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a Deployment Profile. It is in the "New" menu under the General category. Select the type of deployment (JAR File, WAR File, EAR File, etc). It will prompt you for a name and then will give you the options for inclusion, exclusion, etc.

It will then show this deployment profile under the Project, under the Resources heading. You can then right click it to actually perform the EAR file deployment.

Answer (score 1):

While you are creating the deployment profile, make sure that you have a WAR file if you have an UI component in your project. And in the application assembly segment, it is sufficient if you specify just the war file and add the model jar file as a dependency to the war file.